# request.body is coming back undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, mailchimp

So I'm passing user entered data to the backend, but req.body is coming back undefined and i'm not sure why. I've set up my middleware beforehand, yet I still get undefined. I have also checked the the value being sent by axios and has checked out to be correct.

```
app.use(Cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    //const { email } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body.email);
    if(!req.body.email) {
        console.log("No email, failed");
        return;
    }
    const data = {
        members: [
            {
                email_address: req.body.email,
                status: "subscribed"
            }
        ]
    }

    const postData = JSON.stringify(data);
    const options = {
        url: 'https://us4.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/xxxxxx',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'xxxxxxx'
        },
        body : postData
    }

    request(options, (err, response, body) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                if(response.statusCode === 200) {

                    console.log("Success!");
                }else {

                    console.log("Error Accessing")
                    res.send("Error");
                }
            }       
        });
});
```

Here is my axios post method:

```
handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { email } = this.state;
        axios
        .post('http://localhost:5000/signup', email)
        .then(() => console.log("Email Added"))
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    };
```

Comment: what is the value of the email when you made the call?

Comment: The value printed before the call is made is the email I put in to the form, so it is being passed to state correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have confirmed that what is being POSTed by axios (this.state.email) is not undefined?

The fact that the req body is coming back undefined points to either the data being entered incorrectly or the request for that data being invalid.

What does the entire req.body look like?

Comment: req.body is coming back as an empty object

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was that I was not passing email as an object, hence the object was coming back empty.